# API Calls from AWS Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, logging, aws-glue

I am running an AWS Glue job written from scratch to read from database and save the result in s3.
I would like to set an HTTP API call to send the status of the Glue job after completing the read from database whether it was success or fail (which acts as a logging service). Is this possible from AWS Glue?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is possible. You need to set up a VPC, with a public and a private subnet. In the private subnet, you can create an ENI that will allow only outbound connections for Glue to call the API. In the public subnet, you can install a NAT Gateway.